# Meteor - Display the Email Address of the Logged In User

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am trying to display the email address of the logged in user with Meteor.

I am using the command Meteor.user().emails[0].address -- and this works sometimes only. Other times it is undefined. This is because sometimes the page renders before the User's collections is available.

However, I am using React and not blaze. Every solution online suggests using Meteor.subscribe() in the onCreated part of the template. But I cannot figure out React's equivalent and I cannot figure out how to wait for the User collection before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to use Meteor.autorun which accepts a callback function that runs whenever Meteor's reactive sources update.**

Meteor.subscribe accepts an `onReady` optional callback. I would attach to the `componentWillMount` lifecycle event on your React component, setup your meteor subscription, and cause a state change once `onReady` has fired. Here is some rough example code;

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    var _this = this;

    // Setup meteor subscription
    Meteor.autorun(function () {
      _this.setState({
        user: Meteor.user(),
      });
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    // Render nothing until we have a user
    if (!this.state || !this.state.user) {
      return null;
    }

    // Render the address when we have the user

    return (
      <div>{this.state.user.emails[0].address}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Relevant docs: http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't display. What should my publish command look like?

Comment: Updated to use Meteor.autorun. I am not super familiar with Meteor code, so I can't say for sure why you can't subscribe to the Users collection. Autorun executes its callback whenever a reactive source changes, so it works well for this case. Here is a blog post discussing Autorun https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/